# how to use a SWIG generated C++ class in a java program

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am successfully building a shared library that is C++ and loading it in my Java program with System.loadLibrary()

My class in the C++ file was called Classifier

How do I instantiate a new "Classifier" object in java? Do I have to compile and include the java files that are generated from Swig to do such a thing? If I do not want to do that, can I just use the methods from the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used correctly, SWIG will have generated a wrapper Java class called "Classifier."

Yes, this needs to be compiled -- e.g., by including it in your IDE project and/or your build.

[The SWIG documentation for Java](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Java_classes) shows how to instantiate a C++ object from Java:

> C++ classes are wrapped by Java classes as well. For example, if you have this class,

```
class List {
public:
  List();
  ~List();
  void insert(char *item);
  ...
```

> you can use it in Java like this:

```
List l = new List();
l.insert("Ale");
...
```

A few other thoughts:

- You can ask SWIG to place the Java class in a package of your choosing, with the -package option on the SWIG command line.
- I personally keep generated code in a separate source tree. You'll be periodically deleting it, and don't want to accidentally delete non-generated code.
- If you do not need access to any C++ classes in your Java code, you might find JNA easier to work with than SWIG.

Comment: I'll preface this with I dont know what JNA is - but is all of the steps they have outlined necessary when you just want to use C++ functions (user defined), but they are not in the class context? I seem to have been able to load the library, and just use functions by declaring them as native in my java class, and never had to compile any additional java

Comment: Java native functions are declared in Java and implemented in C, possibly with some JNI. SWIG uses native functions to communicate between its Java wrappers and its native glue code. Using SWIG should not require you to hand-write any Java native methods. If you are writing your own Java native methods by hand, you should need to implement them on the native side.